# Is it possible to use Java enum to translate letters into numbers?

Tags: java, enums

I am very new to java. I need to write a program that input an English text and translate it into numbers according to the following correspondence: a to 0, b to 1...z to 26, the period "." to 27, comma "," to 28, "?" to 29, "(" to 30, and ")" to 31. I wonder whether it is possible to use enum to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, this is possible with enum, but I recommend you don't do it with enum. If you really want your own numbering scheme, you should use a map. I suggest you stick to ASCII codes, though.

Comment: Map is cool! I'll try map! Could you give me a specific answer on map, jlordo?

Comment: I don't why it is closed as too localized by editors: Mat, Randy, Reimeus, Guru, p.s.w.g. this is good question to ask, all chars is definitely a kind of enums. they can be wrapped to use. it sounds like `fly weight` design pattern.

Answer (score 3):

That's not something Java-specific. For a computer, characters are just numeric values corresponding to some code: ASCII, Unicode or whatever. So in most programming languages (including Java) you should find means to treat letters as numbers. In Java you have the `char` primitive type (and the `Character` object wrapper) which you can use here.

You just need to do some basic arithmetics in order to get to the mapping that you need.

Comment: Exactly. Using the fact that `char` is a numeric type is a much better fit than any approach using an `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
public static int letterToInt(char ch) {
    return (ch & 31) - 1;
}
```

if you a specific list of letters in mind you can do

```
public static int letterToInt(char ch) {
    return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,?()".indexOf(ch);
}
```

Maps 'a' or 'A' to 0 and 'b' or 'B' to 1 etc.  Note: a-z is either 1 to 26 or 0 to 25.